# How to enable single-word selection in a Dash DataTable cell using dash_table.DataTable?

Tags: python, plotly-dash

I have created a table using dash_table.DataTable in Dash. Currently, when I double-click a cell, the entire cell is selected, and I have to use arrow keys to navigate left and right to edit something. However, I want the cell to behave like an HTML input, allowing me to see my cursor where I click and select a single word with a double click. How can I achieve this behavior?

Comment: Please do not replace the title and content of your question with a completely different one. Rather, post a [new question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask).